# How to connect QSqlTableModel with QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtsql

i want a simple example of connecting QSqlTableModel  with QTableView ,
connecting the QSqlTableModel to dataset file (*.db) then connecting it to QTableView  ?

semi code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.resize(600, 600)
    main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details)? At the very beginning there's an example showing how to do it; it's written in C++, but it's very simple and it's also pretty clear what it does (just consider that `->` becomes the simple period character `.` for python).

Comment: i really looked at it but since i didn't see the part which uses the file name of the database i considered it out of reach as it won't connect to my database afterall. @musicamante

Comment: See [SQL Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.html) (including its sections, specifically "Connecting to Databases") and [QSqlDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is:

- Open the database through QSqlDatabase
- Then load the table into the model, and
- at the end set the model in the view.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("/path/of/database.db")
    if not db.open():
        sys.exit(-1)

    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable("your_table")
    model.select()

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_()
```

**Note:** In the case of sqlite if the database does not exist then it will create it so `db.open()` rarely returns false.